# Programmatical use of npm in node's REPL

Tags: node.js, npm, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to programatically use the npm module to install modules. Putting the following code in a file.js:

```
var npm = require('npm');

npm.load({ 
    save : true,
    loglevel : 'warn'
}, function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    npm.commands.install(['async']);
});
```

works just fine:

```
$ node file.js
async@0.2.9 node_modules/async
[ [ 'async@0.2.9', 'node_modules/async', '', undefined, 'async@' ] ]
```

However, running the same code in the node interpreter results in the following error message:

```
$ node
> var npm = require('npm');
undefined
> npm.load({save : true,loglevel : 'warn'},function(err){if (err) return callback(err);npm.commands.install(['async']);});
undefined
> 
/path/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:52
    env.npm_execpath = require.main.filename
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at /path/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:52:36
    at /path/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:128:12
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Both alternatives install the module though. Do I have to set any special variable when I'm running `npm.commands.install` in the REPL?

EDIT: npm (1.3.22), node (v0.10.24)

Comment: I understand some time has come since then, but do you by any chance remember how you had solved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require.main` is not set on the REPL. If you take a look at it from a Node.js script, it looks like this:

```
{ id: '.',
  exports: {},
  parent: null,
  filename: '/Users/btilley/test.js',
  loaded: false,
  children: [],
  paths:
   [ '/Users/btilley/node_modules',
     '/Users/node_modules',
     '/node_modules' ] }
```

I'm guessing npm uses the `filename` attribute (and probably others) to resolve paths and the like. You could probably fake it out during a REPL session by setting all the right attributes; you might also take a look at the [npm CLI source](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/bin/npm-cli.js) to see how sets up and/or uses this data.

Comment: For further reference, see the [modules definition of the CommonJS specification](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1#Require): *The "require" function may have a "main" property*. *This attribute, when feasible, should be read-only, don't delete.*

Comment: @BinaryMuse the current npm CLI source doesn't contain the code that sets up this data...